# The equilibrium constant of a reaction only involving pure solid or liquid

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium

How to calculate the equilibrium constant of a reaction only involving pure solid or liquid.
For example reaction
$$\ce{S(s) + Hg(l) -> HgS(s)}$$
or
$$\ce{S(s) + Mg(s) -> MgS(s)}$$

Comment: Do a quick search for "equilibrium constant solids", there are several questions which are of help to you.

Answer (score 1):

Concentration of  pure solids and liquids is conventionally taken to be 1. Since reaction involves only solids and liquids the equilibrium constant will be 1